# Dash app stops when I import dependencies

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I just started using Plotly dash to create a web application, I successfully deployed dash using flask and apache on an ubuntu 18.04 server.

I ran the example codes found in https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload and it works successfully.

The app stops loading once I try to import other dependencies like scipy or sklearn or any other installed dependencies

```
import base64
import datetime
import io

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table

import pandas as pd
import scipy
import sklearn
```

I checked that the dependencies are installed correctly. Does anyone have a suggestion of what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: No, it just keep loading without giving me anything.
when I undo my edit, it works again just fine.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: it seems like Apache needed some configurations to access my installed libraries.

I used Nginx and it solved the problem.